# caculating dates with php

Tags: php

I have a general question on calculating dates with php.

What happens if I store a timestamp like this in my database:

```
$db_timestamp = '2010-01-31 00:00:00';
```

and then run a daily script that checks if a month has passed since the timestamp was saved in the database:

```
if ($db_timestamp == make_unix_timestamp(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 1, date("d"), date("Y")), TRUE, 'eu'))) 
{ 
    do something 
};
```

my problem is that i just realized that this wouldn't work for all dates. in this case 'do something' would not be called in February, since February doesn't have a 31st day. any idea on how to implement something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your DBMS should have a data type for date/time. They all store timestamps in a similar way.

MySQL then provides a function called [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) if you need to return a timestamp PHP can understand.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`createTime`) FROM `articles`;
```

The opposite function is called [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime):

```
INSERT INTO `articles` (`createTime`) VALUES ( FROM_UNIXTIME(12345678) );
```

MySQL (or another DBMS for that matter, but I'm using MySQL as an example) has a slew of other functions to calculate time differences. For example, to know if an article is more than one month old, use can use [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT * FROM `articles`
  WHERE `article`.`createTime` <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

(In MySQL5 and above, you can also write it as such)

```
SELECT * FROM `articles`
  WHERE `article`.`createTime` <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: thanks! this is great. the only problem here is that mysql outputs '2010-02-28' for '2010-01-31' + 1 MONTH whereas php mktime outputs '2010-03-03' when utilizing date('m') + 1 :(

Comment: @Frank: MySQL's calculation is valid here. If you want to calculate 30 days, use `INTERVAL 30 DAY`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ts = strtotime($db_timestamp);
if ($ts < (time() - 2592000))
{
   do something;
}
```

2592000 seconds = 30 days

Answer (score 1):

You could use date_diff https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
or do a comparison of the timestamp in your database with

```
strtotime("-1 month");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the timestamp using a query:

MySQL:

```
select date from table where date < now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how you consider "*one month*".

If "one month" means "30 days", a solution would be to compare the timestamp you get from the database with the current timestamp :

```
$db_timestamp = strtotime('2010-01-31');
$current_timestamp = time();
var_dump( ($current_timestamp - $db_timestamp) / (24*3600) );
```

If the difference is 30 days... that's it.

A couple of notes :

- [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) converts a date to an UNIX timestamp-- i.e. the number of seconds since 1970-01-01
- [`time`](http://php.net/time) returns the current UNIX timestamp
- you can compare timestamps : they only represent a number of seconds ; and there are 24*60*60 seconds per day ;-)

Comment: one month is the same day, just one month later. the only problem i have with this is, that if a user activates an account on 1-31, there is no 2-31 - yet, the last day in february isn't 30 days after 1-31 either... tricky :(